# How do you properly set up a badger or pig farm?

Tags: towns

I decided to give Towns another chance and I am now 1 year into the game. However, my badgers and pigs keep starving, even though I have made a workers group with 2 townies in it and their only assigned job is feeding.

Also, there seems to be no drawback that the pigs starve other than producing a lot of bones. Can anyone clarify this feature? Is it broken or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you do not have enough workers dedicated to harvesting wheat, even though you have 96 tiles. Because not enough wheat is being harvested to feed the animals, your workers that are dedicated to feeding do not have enough wheat to actually feed the pigs/badgers. If they are just standing around, this is why.

All that you need to do is redistribute your workers. Take half of one of the feeding groups and set it to just harvest (add the other half to your other feeding group). If more animals than you like are still dying, assign more townies to harvesting. If you want more to die, do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to grow wheat which the townies will use to feed the pigs. It's not just a free action. And the downside is that they don't produce meat when they starve.

Comment: I produce a lot of wheat, they still starve. I have actually 96 tiles of wheat. So that cannot be the problem.

Comment: What do the townies assigned to feeding them do?

Comment: Obviously not feeding them..

Comment: Clearly. Are they just standing around? Are they doing other activities?